# Delphi 6 FormatSetting uLkJson.pas

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

I have a problem in a project that I have taken on. `uLkJSON.pas` is used, but the problem is that the `TFormatSetting` function is not present in the Delphi 6 version of the `SysUtils` unit. Can this be updated?

The problem occurs at the point:

```pascal
uses windows,
  SysUtils,
{$IFNDEF KOL}
  classes,
{$ELSE}
  kol,
{$ENDIF}
  variants;

type
  TlkJSONtypes = (jsBase, jsNumber, jsString, jsBoolean, jsNull,
    jsList, jsObject);

class function TlkJSON.GenerateText(obj: TlkJSONbase): string;
var
{$IFDEF HAVE_FORMATSETTING}
  fs: TFormatSettings;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `TFormatSettings` isn't a function, but a type. A record type, to be precise.

Comment: I'd question whether or not you are using the right version of Delphi to compile this. In your shoes I would do some digging to identify this vital information.

Comment: Are you suggesting `uLkJSON.pas` does not work even with `HAVE_FORMATSETTING` undefined? Please clarify the real problem.